# Variable scope in c#: Not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, scope

Consider this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string str;
        int x;

        for (x = 1; x < 10; x++)
        {
            str = "this";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

When i compile i get: Error  Use of unassigned local variable 'str' (I understand this part)

If i change for loop to if then it works fine. why so (confused here) ??

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string str;
        int x;

        if (true)
        {
            str = "this";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What is the reason for this different behavior?. I expected it should give same result in both situations.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With static analysis, the compiler knows for sure that your `if` statement will run and that `str` will be assigned.

Change your 2nd example to

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string str;
        int x;
        bool b = true; // With "const bool" it would work, though

        if (b)
        {
            str = "this";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

and you will have the same behavior as the `for` loop.

The compiler doesn't know for sure that your `for` loop will be executed even if *you* know it will be, so that's why it's telling you about the unassigned variable. A more sophisticated compiler might be able to see that your variable is fine in this case, but handling all such cases is a very complicated problem.

If `x` was a constant (which makes no sense in a `for` loop since you want to increment it...) the compiler would be able to see that 1 is indeed smaller than 10 and it wouldn't warn you about the unused variable. Of course the loop would run forever now, but I'm saying this just to highlight that the compiler can only be sure about constants.

Comment: @Vache What is static analysis ??

Comment: @Cody A simple definition would be "analysis of a program's code without running it". See [What is static code analysis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716/what-is-static-code-analysis) here on SO and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) on the subject.

Comment: @Vache Basically your answer is we are smarter than the IDE, which i think is incorrect.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Please elaborate, I don't see why you're drawing that conclusion.

Comment: @Vache It has more memory, faster execution time, and can read binary.

Comment: @CalvinSmith I still don't get why you're saying that. A compiler is programmed by a humans. The humans who programmed the C# compiler decided it was not relevant for it to be able to decide if a `for` loop executed for sure or not when there are no constants involved. This has nothing to do with anyone being smarter than someone else.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that in the first case the compiler considers a case where loop is never executed:

```
for (x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
    str = "this";
}
```

So it assumes that `str` may stay uninitialized.

---

In the second case, the condition is always `true`, so compiler considers that `str` is always initialized:

```
if (true)
{
    str = "this";
}
```

Comment: Put another way, compilers will often take: `if(true) { x(); }` and turn it into `x();`

Comment: I'm actually curious to know why the compiler can't evaluate the loop. X inside the the loop is assigned the value 1 and is compared against the constant 10. By performing [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) the compiler should know that the body always gets executed. Why is not the case?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Well, in general case `x` can be changed by another thread right before comparison.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange agreed. I also want to know

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: Since this is a question-and-answer site, you could have your curiosity answered by posting a question. Before you do, here's a question for you. Suppose I wrote `int x; if (ThereIsAProofOfFermatsLastTheorem()) { x = 123; } int y = x;`  Would you expect the compiler to try to produce a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, succeed, and conclude that `x` is assigned?  If the answer is "no", then perhaps you would care to state **precisely** which predicates the compiler should deduce are true and which are not, and how the deduction should be carried out.

Comment: @EricLippert I understand your argument. In this case however, the loop is defined **immediately** after the variable. There's no statement that in between the two that could **directly** change `x`. On the other hand, if `x` was a reference type, it is possible that by the time the loop is executed, someone else modifies the value `x` points to (e.g. in a multi-threaded scenario as AlexD mentioned) which would render static evaluation invalid, which is why I think the compiler doesn't bother to perform constant propagation because it's risky.

Comment: I'd actually like to hear your thoughts on this since if I'm not mistaking you had a hand in writing the C# compiler. If you think the question is worth posting or if the answer is too long, I'd gladly post it as its own question.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: The compiler *could* perform that analysis, but the definite assignment rules are designed to be *simple to implement* and *simple to understand*. The compiler tracks only *definite assignment* and does not do any control flow analysis beyond analysis where *only constants are involved*.  So `if (0 == 0) x = 123;` would consider `x` to be definitely assigned. Would you consider x to be definitely assigned if we had `int x; if (rand() * 0 == 0) { x = 123; } print(x);` ?  After all *you* know that any random integer times zero is zero. Should the compiler also know math?

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: This is of course a leading question because in previous versions of the compiler it **did** run the integer optimizer *before* computing definite assignment, which introduced bugs! The point being: clearly there must be some point at which the compiler stops trying to be clever; by design, that point is quite early. The feature desired by the original poster is the feature **let me write awful code**.  The C# language is specifically designed to *prevent* users from writing awful code.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: If this subject interests you, I've written on it quite a bit. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/definite+assignment/ (on *definite assignment*) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/reachability/ (on the closely related topic of *reachability*) for a number of articles on this subject.

Comment: @EricLippert Well, of course it _doesn't have to_, but knowing some basic math (including your example of multiplying a variable by 0) would result in better optimization and reduces number of redundant instructions, don't you think? I guess at the end of the day it's a matter of how far we are willing to push the compiler. I'm not sure what sort of optimizations MSBuild does. Time to dig into Roslyn :)

Comment: And the answer to the question above is: what if `rand()` throws an exception which is caught, and the catch block uses `x`?  Then `x` must *not* be definitely assigned. These problems are surprisingly tricky, and the language designers were wise to be conservative.

Comment: @EricLippert `catch` cannot use `x`, since it will be a different scope. (I do not argue with your reasoning in general, just wanted to address this particular detail :).)

Comment: @AlexD: True, it would have to be `int x; try { if (...) ... } catch ... `

Answer (score 2):

The compiler cannot be certain that a `for` loop will actually iterate.  It could loop 0 times.  An `if(true)` statement is known to the compiler to unconditionally execute.

While, in theory, a suitably advanced compiler *could* reason that the first code block does in fact unconditionally execute, solving the problem in the general case is impossible (you run into the Halting Problem).  The compiler is forced to use heuristics to take a reasonable guess at whether or not a given statement is reachable.  If it states that a path is not reachable you can know with certain that it is not reachable.  If it says that it is reachable it may be reachable, or it may be a false positive.